# I need help producing a pyramid with a certain algorithm to combine numbers (nested loops)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, pascals-triangle

I have the layout for the pyramid set I just can't find out how I would combine or mathematically get the next few numbers. What I need is:

```
       1
     1 2 1
    1 3 3 1
   1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
```

My code right now is:

```
int x = 7;
for (int i =1; i<=x; i++) {
    for (int j =1; j<=x-i; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int k=1; k<=i;k++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d",k);
    }
    for(int k=i-1; k>=1;k--) {
        System.out.printf("%2d",k);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

But my output comes out as:

```
            1
          1 2 1
        1 2 3 2 1
      1 2 3 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
  1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Sorry if this came out weird; this is my first question ever on this site. How can I modify my code to get the other pyramid?

Comment: [`string.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: I edited the code in your question to make its indentation match its structure, so answerers can help more easily. I don’t know if the indentation only got garbled when you pasted your code on this site, but if not, maybe looking at this new indentation will let you find any bugs more easily.

Comment: The pyramid of numbers you are trying to produce is called [Pascal’s triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: Is your output required to be indented so that each line is exactly centered? Or is it okay if just the left edge is a straight diagonal line, like it is in your current output, even if the right edge is lopsided? Centering the text perfectly would be harder.

Comment: The numbers need to be centered.

Comment: If you could help me how to just get the numbers even the left side straight, I could figure out the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I presume you are trying to compute a [Pascal triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) and that when you wrote that the desired output was:

```
       1
     1 2 1
    1 3 3 1
   1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
```

you actually mean:

```
       1
      1 1
     1 2 1
    1 3 3 1
   1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
```

because otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

Assuming you have made a slight error and the second triangle is the one you want then that is a Pascal's triangle. The rules for computing a Pascal triangle is to add the number above and to the left with the number above and to the right to find the new value.

[image: Pascal Triangle]

[Image credit Hersfold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Hersfold)

You can quite easily write a recursive function that will do this.  With a recursive function a good approach is to write your guards and base case, then recurse.  This would look like:

```
private static int calculatePascalNumber(int row, int column)
{
    if (row < 1 || column < 1 || column > row) {
        return 0;
    } else if (column == 1 || row == column) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return calculatePascalNumber(row - 1, column - 1) + 
                    calculatePascalNumber(row - 1, column);
    }
}
```

These are the rules for this function

- if the row or column is less than 1 or the column is wider than the
  row these are points outside of the triangle and should return 0
- if the column is in one of the end columns (either column equals 1 or the row and column are equal) return 1
- otherwise add the two numbers above to the left and the right

You could then call this function within your code that would look like

```
int x = 7;
for (int row = 1; row <= x; row++) {

    for (int j =1; j<=x-row; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    for (int column=1; column<=row;column++) {
        System.out.printf(" %2d", calculatePascalNumber(row, column));
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

I have revised it a little for formatting, if you wanted to put in further work the ouput formatting would be a good thing to look at.

Finally, it is worth noting performance.  If you wanted to run this to compute values on large triangles the number of recursive calls would start making this function go very slowly.  A possible way to resolve this would be to cache the results of calls to calculatePascalNumber so that when it is called with parameters it has already computed it returns the value from a hashmap/ array rather than running through all the computations multiple times.

Another option to speed this up for larger triangles is to use [this function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself) for calculating a row by itself which could lead to the following code for calculatePascalNumber

```
private static int calculatePascalNumber(int row, int column)
{
    if (row < 0 || column < 0 || column > row) {
        return 0;
    } else if (column == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (calculatePascalNumber(row, column - 1) 
                  * (row + 1 - column)) / (column - 1); 
    }
}
```

but what you gain with efficiency you lose with clarity.